# Is there a notation for $f(x,y) - f(y,x)$?

Tags: notation

Suppose we have a function $f(x,y)$ in two variables. Is there an operator on the function, say, $$([]f)(x,y) = f(x,y) - f(y,x)?$$

In other words, I'm looking for a commutator in terms of function arguments.

Comment: By analogy with the odd part of a function and the antisymmetric part of a matrix, you might say that your operator gives twice the anticommutative part of the function.

Comment: I don't know of any general notation either, but I propose $[x, y]_f$.  Note, $[x, y] = xy - yx$ is the ring-theoretic commutator, based on the multiplication function, $m(x,y) = xy$, so the new notation would agree well with established notation: $[x, y]_m = xy - yx = [x, y]$.  Just a thought.

Comment: I really like $[x,y]_f$.